# Access violation in char double pointer program

Tags: c++, pointers, char

This piece of code gives me runtime exception: `Unhandled exception at 0x00401189 in ControlFileChanges.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xbaadf00d` at the first strcpy command.

```
char** withStrings(string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4, string s5)
{
char** pipes;
pipes = (char**) malloc(sizeof(*pipes)*5);

strcpy(pipes[0],s1.c_str());
strcpy(pipes[1],s2.c_str());
strcpy(pipes[2],s3.c_str());
strcpy(pipes[3],s4.c_str());
strcpy(pipes[4],s5.c_str());

return pipes;
}
```

Any idea what the problem could be?
(This is a sample that I am using to use similar logic in my actual code).

Comment: This is insane code, even if it weren't wrong. It's definitely not "C++".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't allocate memory to `pipes[0]`, `pipes[1]`, etc.

Since this is C++ and not C, did you consider using `new` instead of `malloc` ? Or maybe use a `vector` or `string`s ?

Comment: Could you please give me the equivalent C++ code with new instead of malloc (just for allocating memory to pipes, not to the individual strings in pipes)

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala the equivalent code in C++ doesn't use new at all. You use a vector of strings and the `withStrings` function doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 2):

The constant `0xbaadf00d` tells us a lot here. It indicates that you're using Microsoft, you've allocated some heap memory in debug mode and not initalized it.

You can see this - you've called `malloc()` to make your `char**`, but not set each of the `char*` pointers individually to point to anything valid before calling `strcpy`. That is to say since `char**` is a pointer to a pointer allocating just the `char**` allocates you pointers to pointers, but not anything for them to point at.

If you can I'd suggest avoiding the C strings entirely.

Answer (score 0):

`char** pipes;` - is an array of pointer which will store address of 5 strings. So you have allocated memory for storing the address of 5 strings in the below statement.

pipes = (char**) malloc(sizeof(*pipes)*5);

After this you have to allocate memory for storing each string. So update your code like below.

```
#define MAX_NO_STRING 5
#define MAX_STR_SIZE 50

pipes = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*MAX_NO_STRING); 
for(i = 0; i < MAX_NO_STRING; i++)
{
    pipes[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_STR_SIZE);
}
```

Note : Take care of NULL check for malloc